# c# asp.net Form with a submit button and a button that executes a command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, form-submit

basically i have a form with the runat server tag. within this form i have an asp repeater and asubmit button- but i also want to have a button which will call a c# method in my code - can someone please give me an idea as to how to go about this? Also in this code the selectindexchanged event does not fire even though its autopostback value is true which is weird :/

thanks

**Edit**
OK solution seems to be remove the action tab and i have then set the property through some JavaScript instead :) why cant things be straightforward

---

```
    <form action="broadcast.aspx" id="bcForm" runat="server" onsubmit="chkChecks()"> 
            <a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" title="Create new product"> <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Create new product</a> &nbsp &nbsp <a id="bcItems" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" title="Broadcast" onclick="chkItems()"><i class="icon-share icon-white"></i> Broadcast</a>

</br></br>
<p>Filters:
<asp:DropDownList ID="groupFilter" runat="server" ToolTip="Groups"        AutoPostBack="True" onselectedindexchanged="groupFilter_SelectedIndexChanged1" ></asp:DropDownList></p>


   <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="DepartmentList" runat="server"  OnItemmDataBound="DepartmentsList_ItemDataBound">
   <HeaderTemplate>
         <table id="grouptable" class="table table-bordered table-striped sortable"> 
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th class="sorttable_nosort" >Broadcast 
                                <br> </br><a class="label label-inverse" onclick="checkAll()">Check All</a>&nbsp<a class="label label-inverse" onclick="uncheckAll()">Uncheck All</a></th>
                            <th class="sorttable_numeric">ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Last Modified</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                            <td WIDTH="100">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="BroadcastSelect[]" value="<%# Eval("DEPT_ID") %>"</input></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("DEPT_ID") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("DESC") %></td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CHG_DATE") %>'></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-info" href="<%# Eval("gURL") %>">Edit</a>&nbsp;&nbsp<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger">Broadcast Now</asp:HyperLink></td>
                            </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                </div>



              <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" runat="server">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; Select A Branch</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h4>Test</h4>

                <asp:Repeater ID="cfgList" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                   <table id="configtable" class="table table-bordered table-striped"> 
                    <thead>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Broadcast</th>
                            <th>Branch No.</th>
                            <th>Branch Name</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                            <tr>
                            <td>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="BranchSelection[]" value="<%# Eval("branch") %>"</input></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("branch") %></td>
                            <td><%# Eval("name") %></a> </td>
                            </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                            </tbody>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>


                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <!--<a class="btn btn-success" onclick="document.getElementById('bcForm').submit()" title="Broadcast"><i class="icon-share icon-white"></i> Broadcast</a> -->
                  <a class="btn btn-success" onclick="chkBranches()" title="Broadcast"><i class="icon-share icon-white"></i> Broadcast</a>
                  <!--<input type="submit" value="Broadcast3" class="btn btn-success"/> -->
                  <div id="myDiv"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary">Broadcast Testing</a> -->
                <!--<a class="btn btn-success" onclick="document.getElementById('bcForm').submit()" title="Broadcast"><i class="icon-share icon-white"></i> Broadcast</a>-->
                <a id="bcItems2" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-primary" title="Broadcast" onclick="chkItems()"><i class="icon-share icon-white"></i> Broadcast</a>
                <ul class="pager">
                <li>
                <asp:Button ID="previousBtn" runat="server" Text="Prev" cssclass="search-query" 
                        Width="80px"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                <asp:Button ID="nextBtn" runat="server" Text="Next" cssclass="search-query" 
                        Width="80px"/>
                </li>
                </ul>
                </form>
```

Comment: you can simply do that by double clicking on the button. As soon as you do that, it will generate a button_click event for you. You can then write your logic there or call a method there. R

Comment: `runat` does not do anything with asp.net controls.  That's there for html support.

Comment: remove the action attribute first from the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the action attribute first from the form. – DotNet Dreamer

this was basically the answer, check the original post which i have updated with the fix :)

props to DotNet Dreamer

Answer (score 5):

I must be missing something in your question, because this isn't difficult, but here you go...

HTML:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Whatever" OnClick="SomeMethod_Click"/>
```

C# code behind

```
public void SomeMethod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

Comment: this only works if i remove the action tab in the form as stated by someone below, otherewise it will always submit

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
<script runat="server">
Sub submit(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
lbl1.Text="Your name is " & txt1.Text
End Sub
</script>

<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
Enter your name:
<asp:TextBox id="txt1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button OnClick="submit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
<p><asp:Label id="lbl1" runat="server" /></p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

link for help: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_button.asp

Comment: problem was that the action tag was overriding anything i tried to do - i actually know how button work but thanks for the reply nonetheless :)

Comment: No problem, sorry not to be more help, glad u fixed it!

Answer (score -3):

In the dropdownlist property, you can set AutoPostBack = true. With this it will send the post back to server therefore event can be triggered.

oh. sry i didn't see you already have it